# Impala Hue Cloudera : How to find tenure from the given columns 'account opened' and 'account closed' (both are int) in a dataset

Tags: impala

I am trying to calculate the tenure from the two columns 'account opened' and 'account closed' (both are int) in my deposit data. I tried to use the following formats:

1. datediff(TIMESTAMP enddate, TIMESTAMP startdate)
2. datediff(to_date(account opened),now()) and datediff(to_date(account closed),now()) however, fail to get the output.

Please assist.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If dates are in `INT/BIGINT` type means they are `UNIXTIME` format. So you need to convert them to timestamp before comparing. You can do it in many ways. One of them below -

1. convert the unixtime to timestamp using below function
   `to_timestamp(from_unixtime(1392394861,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')`
2. Use `datediff` to find out difference in date.
   `datediff(to_timestamp(from_unixtime(account_opened,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), to_timestamp(from_unixtime(account_closed,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))`

So, here is the whole SQL to get difference in dates-

```
SELECT 
datediff(to_timestamp(from_unixtime(account_opened,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), to_timestamp(from_unixtime(account_closed,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) as datediff_int 
from TABLE
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kaushik :-). However, i am not getting the tenure of the account opened or tenure of the account closed. I have been trying the following code however, Impala/Hive gives error 

rec_dt= substr(podium_delivery_date, 1, 6)  {podium delivery date is the record date}
open_dt = substr(cast(acount_opened as string),1,6)
closed_dt = substr(cast(acount_closed as string),1,6)

Comment: (CAST(LEFT(bb.rec_dt, 4) AS INT)-CAST(LEFT(bb.open_dt, 4) as INT))*12 +
 if(CAST(RIGHT(bb.rec_dt, 2) AS INT) > (CAST(RIGHT(bb.open_dt,2) as INT)),
   CAST(RIGHT(bb.rec_dt, 2) AS INT) - CAST(RIGHT(bb.open_dt,2) as INT), 
CAST(RIGHT(bb.rec_dt, 2) AS INT) + CAST(RIGHT(bb.open_dt,2) as INT)) as Open_Tenure

Comment: (CAST(LEFT(bb.rec_dt, 4) AS INT)-CAST(LEFT(bb.closed_dt, 4) as INT))*12 + 
if(CAST(RIGHT(bb.rec_dt, 2) AS INT) > (CAST(RIGHT(bb.closed_dt,2) as INT)),
  CAST(RIGHT(bb.rec_dt, 2) AS INT) - CAST(RIGHT(bb.closed_dt,2) as INT), 
  CAST(RIGHT(bb.rec_dt, 2) AS INT) + CAST(RIGHT(bb.closed_dt,2) as INT)) as Closed_Tenure

Comment: what do you mean by tenure ? difference in dates?

Comment: by tenure i mean ...I am looking to obtain the 'age in months' of the account since account opened an 'age in months' of the account since account closed.

Comment: so you need to use `months_between()`. Pls find sql below - `SELECT 
months_between(to_timestamp(from_unixtime(account_opened,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'), to_timestamp(from_unixtime(account_closed,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')) as Monthdiff_Double 
from TABLE`. pls note this will give you double type data.